# What is EAQUAL ? How does it relate to PEAQ?

Tags: audio, software-implementation

This [wiki post](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=EAQUAL) on wiki.hydrogenaudio.org says that it is very similar to PEAQ and also a part of ITU-R BS.1387 recommendation ? How reliable it is for determining audio quality.

Are there any other open implementations of PEAQ that are good.

Comment: This question is too broad, I think.  Have you tried searching Google before asking this?  http://www.tech.plym.ac.uk/spmc/links/audio/audio_quality.html  Can you ask something more specific?

Comment: endolith, the link is dead unfortunately